# MATLab crashes on launch OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, matlab, osx-yosemite

I've just installed the OS X Yosemite beta and can't open MATLab 2014a.

It displays this error dialog:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas as to how this could be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary solution:

change the 10.10 in /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist under ProductVersion to 10.9 or lower can solve you the problem.

However, it forbids Safari, Mail from booting. Thus you can only choose one to use a time, and change the ProductVersion back and forth.

Comment: One important note though. This will break Disk Utility. It will notify you that "you cannot use this version of DU with this version of OSX, please use the version of DU in the Utilities folder in Applications". So to use DU, you have to revert the changes to the plist mentioned here.

Comment: This is not a valid answer and should not be practiced by any user.

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE: (OFFICIAL FIX) **

Mathworks has released a patch for Matlab 2012a ~ 2014a. Use [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1098655) to download the appropriate patch for your version

There is another issue with Yosemite Beta 2. It prevents Matlab from running at the very first point with this error message:

> You can’t use this version of the application “MATLAB_R2012b” with this version of OS X.

The solution is:

1. find Matlab application file under Applications folder
2. Right (Control) click and select `Show Package Contents`
3. Navigate to : `Contents/Mac OS`
4. Right (control)  click on `startMatlab`
5. Make an Alias
6. Copy the Alias to another folder e.g. your desktop.
7. Run the alias.

You will still need to have those temporary fixes that were used in Beta 1 for running Matlab.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAMyQEOHWh0) is the tutorial video for fixing the problem (on Beta 2)

and as a reminder [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GoQnzIyOkB0) is the video for fixing crash on Beta 1

Answer (score 3):

Definitive solution. It runs fine without system hacks or desktop aliases.

Download the patch here:
http://files.mc128k.info/data/public/92d26d.php

Comment: I was hesitant to download a patch from an unknown source, but took a chance and had a look. The patch appears to be from MathWorks, and on 2013a does prevent the NullPointerException, but unfortunately appears to hang on the splash screen after that. What's the source of the patch, and what version(s) is it supposed to work with?

Comment: The patch was released by Mathworks of course. See the info file inside. I used it on the 2014 version on Yosemite and it works fine after the splash. 2013 does not work. Tested on my machine.

Comment: This worked for me on 2014a. For those interested, the original patch can be obtained from MathWorks directly as part of this bug report: http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1098655. Info.plist editing or a StartMATLAB alias is still required (c.f http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1116607).

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: While probably very noble of you, please do not offer downloads like these from your personal website (with broken HTTPS). Please refer to an official website instead.

Comment: Sure I thought about it, but filesharing websites often delete content after a while, so the link would be dead after a few months. Will definitely think about something better next time. Any ideas?

Comment: In this case, just linking to the Mathworks.com bug report should be good as software vendors like this generally keep their bug reports and fixes for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

A fix that allows you to launch and run both MatLab and the Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite standard apps all at once is to set the ProductVersion to 10.90 instead of 10.9 or 10.10.

Comment: As mentioned earlier in this thread: One important note though. This will break Disk Utility. It will notify you that "you cannot use this version of DU with this version of OSX, please use the version of DU in the Utilities folder in Applications". So to use DU, you have to revert the changes to the plist mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Edit version number**

It may be easier to change the version number from 10.10 to 10.90 using terminal (especially if you are having permission issues to save your edits like I did). Open terminal and type

`sudo nano -w /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`

enter your password and then you may edit the file and save it. You will need to revert it when you want to use disk utility.

**2. Create alias to open Matlab**

Taken from Behrad3d's answer, you will also need to create an alias to be able to open Matlab:

1- find Matlab application file under Applications folder 2- Right (Control) click and select "Show Package Contents" 3- Navigate to : "Contents/Mac OS" 4- Right (control) click on "startMatlab" file 5- Make an Alias 6- Copy the Alias to another folder e.g. your desktop. 7- Run the alias.

Answer (score 0):

Permanent fix which works with versions R2013b and R2014a:

1. Change the 10.10 in /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist under ProductVersion to 10.90 -this will assure OSX's native apps won't crash.
2. Next step is to change **'Bundle version'** of Matlab from 8.X.X to 9.X.X (basically change only first number to '**9**', leave the rest unchanged). To do so, edit Matlabs Info.plist: /Applictions/Matlab_XXXX/Contents/Info.plist (to access it, you have to right click on Matlab app in Applications and select 'Show Package Contents' as mentioned in the previous posts.

I tested it personally on R2013b and R2014a. It works. Nothing crashes. You might try to apply the same logic to earlier versions of Matlab.